# need to turn separate zsh script into a function inside a master script

Tags: bash, script, zsh

I'm trying to turn 6 scripts into one script, so that instead of the enduser needing to download 6 scripts, do `chmod +x` mess to them etc, and then run the master script, they'd only need one script and be able to accomplish the objective.

The issue is that I've got a loop that goes through a pre-generated textfile, and runs `xargs` on each row of the pre-generated textfile.

The `xargs` then calls one of the 5 scripts, which in turn calls 2 other scripts, and so on.

I've tried to take the script that `xargs` runs, and turn it into a function inside the master-script, but if I just call it by `ideMini` inside the xargs command, I get told that the `ideMini` command does not exist.

Here is what I am working with right now

```
function ideMini() {

whatisit=$(curl -s specificplace/$1 | jq -r)

if [[ "$whatisit" = "xyz" ]]; then
    ./idep.sh $1
elif [[ "$whatisit" = "abc" ]]; then
    ./idmovie.sh $1
fi
}

export -f ideMini

function idDownloads {
echo "ID the downloads?"
select yn in "Yes" "No"; do
  case $yn in
    Yes ) echo "...Identifying downloads for" $email;cut -c110- dlist.txt | xargs -I _ ideMini _ | cat -n;break;;
    No ) break;;
  esac
done
}
```

I've also tried
`xargs -I _ bash -c 'ideMini "$@"' _`

but with no luck.

I'm a little bit confused as to how to proceed. turning the `idep.sh` and `idmovie.sh` into functions within the masterscript would be trivial, but this xargs issue is problematic for me.

Any pointers would be appreciated.

And yes, I'd prefer to just run one script instead of 6. And yep, if I can solve this `xargs` issue the next thing is me trying to copypaste two python scripts into the zsh script and hope for the best. The functionality of the scripts is finished, and there will be no changes, this is just to make it easier to distribute the, err, "app".

Comment: xargs is a child process of your script. As such it does not know anything about zsh-functions. It invokes in turn a child process of your choice. You need to arrange that the command to be executed is your zsh script, with suitable parameters to invoke the function you want to have.

Answer (score 1):

While not a direct answer, you can bypass this by having the functions fallback to env vars when no input is passed

```
function llg() {
  the_path=$1
  [ ! -x $1 ] || ref_branch="$path_from_env"
  [ ! -x $path_from_env ] || the_path='.'
  ll "$the_path" | grep "[0-9][0-9]\(\.[0-9]\)\?M "
}
```

that way, you can `export path_from_env=something` before the function is called.

overall as your complexity increases, you should consider writing the script in ruby or python, rather than writing a bash script.  Most OS builds come with one of those script interpreters installed.

Comment: With Monterey python is not included in macOS